# How to generate a signed POST request for Tumblr using OAuth Swift

Tags: ios, oauth, tumblr, nsurlsession, nsurlrequest

I am trying to get a sample Tumblr client up and running. I am using the OAuth Swift library to do my OAuth.

Right now my project has one button. This button checks to see if OAuth has been authorized or not. If it is, then it is set up to post some hard coded data to a test Tumblr account I set up.

I am getting this output on the console:

`Top of authorizeWithCallbackURL
OAuth successfully authorized
Request error
Server Response:
{"meta":{"status":401,"msg":"Not Authorized"},"response":[]}`

It appears that my token is accepted and an OAuth token is generated, but for some reason it is not being included in the POST request I am trying to call once I have been authorized.

This is my code with the appropriate redactions:

```
import UIKit
import OAuthSwift

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var session:NSURLSession!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func postToTumblr(sender: AnyObject) {
        let oauthSwift = OAuth1Swift(
            consumerKey: "***",
            consumerSecret: "***",
            requestTokenUrl: "https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/request_token",
            authorizeUrl: "https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/authorize",
            accessTokenUrl: "https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/access_token"
        )


        oauthSwift.authorizeWithCallbackURL(NSURL(string: "tumblrsampleapp://oauth-callback")!,
            success: { credential, response in
                // post to Tumblr
                print("OAuth successfully authorized")

                // Configure NSURLSession
                let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.ephemeralSessionConfiguration()
                config.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization":credential]
                self.session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)

                // Post hardcoded data to Tumblr
                let request = self.request("consumerSecretKey&\(credential.oauth_token_secret)")
                let uploadTask = self.session.dataTaskWithRequest(request!) { (responseData, response, error) in

                    // Check on some response headers (if it's HTTP)
                    if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
                        switch httpResponse.statusCode {
                        case 200..<300:
                            print("Success")
                        case 400..<500:
                            print("Request error")
                        case 500..<600:
                            print("Server error")
                        case let otherCode:
                            print("Other code: \(otherCode)")
                        }
                    }

                    // Do something with the response data
                    if let responseData = responseData,
                    responseString = String(data: responseData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
                            print("Server Response:")
                            print(responseString)
                    }

                    // Do something with the error
                    if let error = error {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }

                uploadTask.resume()

            }, failure: {(error:NSError!) -> Void in
                self.presentAlert("Error", message: error!.localizedDescription)
        })
    }

    func request(credential:String) -> NSURLRequest? {
        guard let url = NSURL(string: "https://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/{hostname}/post") else {return nil}
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
        let requestData = self.buildRequestData()

        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.HTTPBody = requestData
        let postDataLengthString = String(format:"%d", requestData.length)
        let credentialString = String(format:"%d", credential)
        request.setValue(postDataLengthString, forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Length")
        request.setValue(credentialString, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        return request
    }

    func buildRequestData() -> NSData {
        // Getting these parameters from this site:
        // https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#posting
        // It looks like there are a bunch of optional paramters
        let requestDictionary = [
            ["type":"text"],
            ["title": "Hello, World!"],
            ["body": "Hello world. This is my first post."]
        ]

        let data = try? NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(requestDictionary, options: NSJSONWritingOptions())

        return data!
    }


    func presentAlert(title: String, message: String) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

I believe the issue involves the `request` function not generating the header properly. I did not see anything in the Tumblr documentation saying that I need to include an authorization token with the request, so I am assuming that they are assuming I am supposed to know that.

Any insight as to what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please give me answer of my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48056353/how-to-get-tumblr-access-token-using-oauth).