# How To Get Tumblr Access Token Using oAuth

Tags: ios, oauth, tumblr

Can anyone tell me how i can get 'Tumblr' access token using oAuth 1.0 or 2. I've read tumblr documentation but i think there is no proper documentation of authentication. I also worked on Instagram, linkedin  and etc using oAuth, but cant understand Tumblr authentication steps. And don't want use tumblr 'sdk' or sample app.

Comment: You don't need to use Tumblr SDK. With OAuth you're good to go.
Note that Tumblr uses OAuth 1 not 2.
Create a new OAuth() instance with the keys and access tokens. 
Call your oauth instance `.authorize` with will open Safari for that - which initially you'll need to implement the `openURL` method in your AppDelegate then call inside it `OAuthSwift.handle(url: url)` and print the given tokens in the credentials completion handler.
And yes, Tumblr's documentation is confusing, they don't specify what fields you'll need to provide in the `parameters` and `headers`

Comment: I have same question